# Cycle List<string> when last item is matched

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have fairly simple `List<string>` that contains reading genres - for display purposes I'll show these individually rather then using the default constructor :

```
List<string> staticSubjects = new List<string>();

staticSubjects.Add("Comic Books & Graphic Novels");
staticSubjects.Add("Literature");
staticSubjects.Add("Mystery");
staticSubjects.Add("Romance");  
staticSubjects.Add("Science Fiction & Fantasy");
staticSubjects.Add("Suspense & Thriller");
staticSubjects.Add("Westerns");
staticSubjects.Add("Biography & Autobiography");
staticSubjects.Add("Careers");
staticSubjects.Add("Computers & Technology");
```

This drives is a list of (8) titles for each genre, and we're giving the user a chance to cycle through all of these genres to view all of those titles.

On the form itself, when the user clicks "Show me more", I'm passing in the current genre that we're displaying titles for, and moving to the next one :

```
var currentGenreIdx = genresToLoad.IndexOf(currentGenre);

// get the next genre based on the index
var nextGenre = genresToLoad[currentGenreIdx + 1];

// set the titles accordingly
titleList = allTitles.Where(x => x.genre.ToLower() == nextGenre.ToLower()).ToList();
```

Now obviously this code is faulty because eventually the index is out of range.

**My question is this** :

Say the user is on my last genre of "Computers & Technology", is there something I can use that will automatically start at the beginning of the list, if I supply it the index of this last item?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers everyone - check goes to Steven since he was first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the MOD operator (`%` in C#):

```
genresToLoad[(currentGenreIdx + 1) % genresToLoad.Count];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
var nextGenre = genresToLoad[(currentGenreIdx + 1) % genreCount];
```

where `genreCount = genresToLoad.Count`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `modulo` function, which returns the rest which remains if the first argument is divided by the second argument. The code would read as follows:

```
// get the next genre based on the index
var nextGenre = genresToLoad[(currentGenreIdx + 1) % genresToLoad.Count()];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nextGenre = genresToLoad[(currentGenreIdx + 1) % genresToLoad.Count];
```